# Synchronize Google Earth to ArcMap and vice versa

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, google-earth, python-addin

I found this old [script](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15944) that worked okay in 9.3, but since I've upgraded to 10.1 the VB code can't work.  It basically allows you to quickly pan in Google Earth to find a feature, then you click on a button and it pans ArcMap to your current extent in GE.  Does anyone know of a python script that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do what you want. I have not tested it myself. 
http://geshout.com/Arc2Google/index.html

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I want it to run in the Google Earth program.  I have a dynamic KML loaded in GE that updates when users rec/post on the SDE.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile this project on my GitHub and it will do exactly what you want it to.

https://github.com/ChrisStayte/ArcMap_To_Google_Earth

Answer (score 0):

I saw a **[post here](http://en.acolita.com/synchronize-arcgis-arcmap-10-with-google-earth.html)** about how to synchronize ArcMap with Google Earth - you can add layer from Google Earth into ArcGIS like that.

Comment: I did it with this post [Synchronize ArcGIS with Google Earth](http://en.acolita.com/synchronize-arcgis-arcmap-10-with-google-earth.html) from Franz's blog. It is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://oman-maps.blogspot.com/2008/03/arcmap-and-google-earth-integration.html) method.  There is also a video showing you how to do it on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNi92pTGtLc).

It's very simple VBA to set up, but it only works to sync GE to ArcMap only.