# Open Google Earth extent in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth

I am trying to get to my Google Earth extent in ArcMap without have to manually pan/zoom around. I do not need Google Earth imagery, just need to view the extent in arcgis. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you open to making tools?  I made an Arcobjects addin which utilized the Google Earth API.  It had two buttons in ArcMap - one to sync Arc to Google, and one to sync Google to Arc.  The API has been deprecated, so you'll have to use an older version of GE.

Comment: I'm not a dev by any means, so no unfortunately. Where can I find your add in?

Comment: I did some Googling around to find an older version of GE.  The GE website has some older versions as well.  See my answer [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65852/synchronize-google-earth-to-arcmap-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Hmm... I didnt see a UIToolControl option under Customize -> Commands. Not sure where I can enter the code. I'm using 10.3 if that makes a difference. I'm wondering if there are any updated add ins that sync ArcMap to Google Earth/Google Maps and vice versa. I havent come across any so far.

Comment: You just need to pass exent to dataframe extent and refresh activeview there is lot of code in this direction on gisstackextchange. If you want syncronize application use google-api-python-client

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I could come up with is to get the lat/long of a point in Google Earth or Google Maps and use the "Go to XY" tool in ArcMap to go that location. From here adjust zoom/extent accordingly.

Comment: I think zoom to bounding box is better. You just need to pass exent to dataframe extent and refresh activeview there is lot of code in this direction on gisstackextchange. If you want syncronize application use google-api-python-client